# Present perfect for three consecutive events

Tags: usage, present-perfect, british-english

John, Peter and Sarah are at a ski resort. John loses his balance and falls down. He then tries to get up, but he can't, so Sarah and Peter call for an ambulance. When it arrives, the doctor says John's leg is broken, so he decides to take him to the hospital. In about an hour, when John is already in the hospital, Peter calls Rick (who's his, Sarah's and John's friend). Rick says to Peter: "How are you, Peter?" To which Peter replies with one of the following versions.

*1. I'm okay, but John **has broken** his leg, and an ambulance **has taken** him to the hospital. We're going to visit him there. Would you like to come with us?*

*2. I'm okay, but John **broke** his leg, and an ambulance **took** him to the hospital. We're going to visit him there. Would you like to come with us?*

*3. I'm okay, but John **broke** his leg, Sarah and I **called** for an ambulance, and it **took** him to the hospital. We're going to visit him there. Would you like to come with us?*

Versions #1 and #2 present the situation from two different perspectives, and they are both correct in this case. I think version #3 is also correct as it stands. But since there are three events in version #3 that happened one after another, I think that in #3 it wouldn't be correct to replace "broke" with "has broken", "called" with "have called", and "took" with "has taken." So version #3 doesn't have a present perfect equivalent in the context given.

Is that correct for British English? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most British English speakers would say "John has broken his leg" (he is currently suffering from the effects of the fracture). We would only say "We have called for an ambulance" if we were still waiting for it to arrive.

Comment: The sequence of events really has no bearing on the present perfect.

Comment: @KateBunting, so only version #1 is correct in my context in British English, right? Thanks.

Comment: This question has been answered many, many times here.

Comment: @KateBunting Come on, please. BrE speakers use the simple past tense all the time. This is not dependent on grammar or BrE or AmE English. It depends on what a speaker **wants to say**.

Comment: Present perfect: The employee has cleaned the office, tidied up the conference room and left the premises. Simple past: The employee cleaned the office, tidied up the conference room and left the premises. And there are other possibilities too. This has zero to do with British English. It concerns speaker intention and time of speaking.

Comment: @Lambie, do you consider all three versions correct in the context given? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they are all fine. That's why I gave another example in my first comment so **you can see the structure** is the same. The tenses can also be mixed in various ways but since there are so many ways to combine them, I'm not going to get into that.

Comment: I **did not** say that 'only #1 is correct', or that British people don't use the simple past. I said that , when reporting a recent accident, we would find it most natural to say "John has broken his leg" (as distinct from "When we went skiing last year, John broke his leg").

Comment: @KateBunting Why are we even arguing? "Oh dear,  John has broken his leg and been taken to hospital."  and "John broke his leg skiing today" are both "natural".

Comment: @Lambie, Does this version work in my context: 4. I'm okay, but John broke his leg, Sarah and I called for an ambulance, and it has now taken him to the hospital. We're going to visit him there. Would you like to come with us?

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice, In American English, version #1 wouldn't be used. The speaker would use either version #2 or version #3. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: @prof1589 No, you are mistaken. There is a myth on the Internet about AmE speakers and the present perfect which is often very wrong. We use the present perfect **all the time**.

Comment: @prof1589  In American English, #1 *could* be used and *would* indeed be used by a considerable percentage of native speakers when "breaking the news" to someone. But I think a much larger percentage of speakers of AmE would use the simple past, #2 and #3.